# Can't see install package in sublime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, sublimetext3

Can't see install package in sublime. I seen this PREFERENCES>>SETTINGS-USER too, but "Package Control" is not there in ignored_packages.

Comment: check out this video: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDsQtwIwBGoVChMIwszFu7fZyAIVCHUeCh2CTAfp&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DoV0P_Y1SWuQ&usg=AFQjCNH5ZTdd1iYCvjGHDaGj6x7KUY-FcA&sig2=Rou7QyVOeImosR0LD86rUA

Comment: This video thing worked thank you.